# Is there a way to get latest value of a metric in Prometheus while ignoring(without) a label?

Tags: prometheus, promql

**PROMQL Query**  that I tried is - `last_over_time(METRIC_ABC{ INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1"}[6h])`

**Returns metrics** -

```
METRIC_ABC{DATE="2022-04-27", INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1", PRODUCT_NAME="PR_1", instance="i_1", job="DB"} 10
METRIC_ABC{DATE="2022-04-27", INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1", PRODUCT_NAME="PR_2", instance="i_1", job="DB"} 15
METRIC_ABC{DATE="2022-04-28", INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1", PRODUCT_NAME="PR_1", instance="i_1", job="DB"} 11
METRIC_ABC{DATE="2022-04-28", INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1", PRODUCT_NAME="PR_2", instance="i_1", job="DB"} 16
```

I would like to get only the latest one while ignoring DATE label. i.e.

```
METRIC_ABC{DATE="2022-04-28", INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1", PRODUCT_NAME="PR_1", instance="i_1", job="DB"} 11
METRIC_ABC{DATE="2022-04-28", INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1", PRODUCT_NAME="PR_2", instance="i_1", job="DB"} 16
```

Is there any way of ignoring a label with last_over_time function or another approach to that?
I am sure this is a common use case so does a function already exists for this which I could not find ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an aggregating function like sum before:

```
last_over_time(sum without (DATE) (METRIC_ABC{ INDICATORNAME="INDICATORNAME_1"}[6h]))
```